Winerror 1392 Python with Selenium
I was running some scripts in python with Selenium and now when I try I get an error.
runfile('C:/Users/Adduntia/Downloads/Sin título1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Adduntia/Downloads')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\adduntia\downloads\sin título1.py:3
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:45 in __init__
    super().__init__(

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:50 in __init__
    self.service.start()

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py:98 in start
    self._start_process(self._path)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py:208 in _start_process
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py:109 in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py:1026 in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py:1538 in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

OSError: [WinError 1392] El archivo o directorio está dañado o es ilegible

The code
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")


You've tagged this with [spyder] - does it behave differently when you run this code within Spyder than when you run it at a simple Python prompt?
